# Extract source code from .pack files

Tags: android, git, repository, pack

I followed the directions on http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html to get the Android source code. Now I have downloaded 2 GB of stuff, most of the space is taken by .pack files. Now how do I access the code?

I tried

```
 git unpack-objects < pack-78609e1ab8b627ff3b749e8d4c78e86e096de3d8.pack
```

the output is:

> Unpacking objects: 100% (14014/14014), done.

Is this the correct way to access the source code and where does it unpack to? Where's the output dir?

Comment: I have updated your formatting but it will time time to be reviewed, please take more care with this when asking questions, you will recieve a better respons if you put more effort into presentaiton.  [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git internally uses objects that are explained here http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html. These objects may be compressed together in a pack. Anyhow, I do not expect you have anything to do with objects and/or packs. So, could you give a bit more detail on the steps you did and the files you ended up with? (Note: I'm not familiar with the Android repo-tool, but I am with git)

Comment: Well I went through all the steps described in the link above, except for the making a working directory part. I just executed repo sync in ~ and now I have a ~/.repo/projects folder that is full of foo.git folders. And all folders have several subdirs and files in 'em.

Comment: When I understand that guide correctly it should put all the files in the current directory, so if you did the `repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git` in `~`, I expect that the `repo sync` should have download the files directly into you home-drectory.  You do not have a directory `~/platform`? Anyhow, I would suggest doing it with the working directory part.

Comment: Okay, I'll start over. But in which format should I expect to see the source code I download?

Comment: I expect it will just extract the source code in your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

the unpacked files are put in the local .git directory. Use:

```
git checkout master
```

to put them in the local directory.